# On click how can I set checkbox to checked?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

When I click the button, I want to set my input checkbox to Checked, but is not working. When I click on a row in my table, the checkbox should be Checked.
A little help please :).

Code:

```
jQuery( ".a-tabel" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).closest('tr').prop('checked', true);
    jQuery('#zone-form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Really hard to help you without seeing the DOM structure/HTML.

Comment: tr doesn't have checked property, find input in row...

Comment: Where is your html code, and you are trying to set checked attribute on tr tag

Comment: Stack Overflow is a **very** active place. When you post a question, please *stick around* for a few minutes so you can answer comments that are asking for clarifications (like "please show your HTML").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is trying to set `checked` on `tr` element, not a checkbox.

If I assume the checkbox is somewhere within the `tr`, then:

```
jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
// -----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```